# Parsing Json Strings as GStrings in Groovy

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, gstring

I am trying to parse a Json file in Groovy which contains a `List` of `String`s. Some of these Strings contain `GString` formatting, and so I hoped to parse these as `GString`s instead of normal `String`s.

For example, the member `description` in the following would contain 1 `GString` and 7 `String`s:

```
{
  ... (other members)
  "description": [
    "This weapon features an alternate firing mode which shoots a tracker grenade.",
    "As a free action, you can switch to the alternate fire mode.",
    "Grenades can be fired up to 30 feet and detonate after 1 round.",
    "Creatures within 15 feet of the grenade must make a Dexterity saving throw.",
    "The save DC is equal to 8 + your Wisdom modifier + your proficiency bonus.",
    "On a failed save, a creature takes ${variables}.get('grenadeDamage').get(${level}) damage and is considered tagged for 2 rounds.",
    "On a success, a creature takes only half the damage and is not tagged.",
    "Attacks with this weapon against tagged creatures have advantage.",
    "However, if any creatures are tagged, this weapon can only attack those creatures."
  ],
  "grenadeDamage": [
    "1d4", "1d4", "1d4", "1d6", "1d6",
    "1d6", "1d8", "1d8", "1d8", "1d10",
    "1d10", "1d10", "2d6", "2d6", "2d6",
    "4d4", "4d4", "4d4", "5d4", "5d4"
  ]
}
```

(I am not used to formatting `GString`s, so it may be incorrect, in which case I apologize)

A `Map` of the additional members (such as `"grenadeDamage"` in the Json file above) would contain mappings of their names to their respective `List`s. These would then be passed into a class laid out as such:

```
class Gun
{
    private int level
    // ... (additional fields)
    private List<?> description
    private Map<String, List<String>> variables

    // ... (Constructors, methods, etc.)

    List<String> getDescription()
    {
        description
    }
}
```

The hope here is to convert any `GString`s in the `List` to regular `String`s when `getDescription()` is called at runtime.

In the given example, if the `level` field was 7, the 5th line of `description` would fill `${variables}.get('grenadeDamage').get(${level})` to the value `1d8`, or the 7th item in `grenadeDamage`.

The issue with this is that when using a `JsonSlurper` to parse the Json file, `description` is created as a `List<String>` directly. Ideally, I would like to parse `description` without immediately enforcing the type as `String`.

Any comments, advice, and constructive criticism is welcome and appreciated!

Comment: You are aware, that this would replace to `[some:map].get('grenadeDamage').get(7)` (this exact text, **not** the dice)? I think you want `${variables.grenadeDamage[level]}` (which will explode once level grows to big). Anyway: have a look at: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/template-engines.html

Comment: transform strings to a templates http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html